# Are there any best practices how to pass multiple parameters in layered java application?

Tags: java, dto, pojo

What should I use instead DTO for grouping parameters?

For example I have two lareys Application and Infrastructure. There is a following class Person on Application layer

```
 Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    String phone;
}
```

On Infrastructure layer I have method `public void notify(String email, String firstName)`

I'd like to create arguments holder:

```
class NotificationDTO {
    String firstName;
    String email; 
}
```

And change method to: `notify(NotificationDTO notification)` 
Is it correct?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Try to be more specific and give some code. As far as I can tell you could take a look at the builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing an instance of the Class created by those different parameters instead. Now that is up to you to decide how you create your model classes. This design is always extensible.

For an example if you are passing for now, fields like username,password,name,email,dob. You should create a class UserCredentials with all these fields as data members.

And then passing the instance of UserCredential class. In case you have lot of params to pass and they are not related in any way, then may be you should rethink about your design.